# How do I play a live HTTP audio stream in MediaPlayer on Android?

Tags: android, media-player

I want to play a live HTTP stream in my Android app, so I installed the Windows Media Encoder 9 on another PC on the same LAN, and used it to create a live HTTP audio stream.

The live HTTP stream is okay: I tested it, and it can be played by Windows Media Player or VLC on a PC, and can be played by VLC for Android on my mobile.

So, in my Android app, I wrote this code:

```
private MediaPlayer player = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectDiskReads()
            .detectDiskWrites()
            .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
            .penaltyLog()
            .build());
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
            .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
            //.detectLeakedClosableObjects()
            .penaltyLog()
            .penaltyDeath()
            .build());

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
    address = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);

    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            play();
        }
    });

}

private void play()
{
    String serverIp;

    serverIp = address.getText().toString(); // get the uri address, for example http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2340

    if (player == null)
    {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
    }
    else
    {
        player.stop();
        player.reset();
    }
    try {
        Log.v("", "Init a new MediaPlayer");

        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        Log.v("", "Set the stream type to STREAM_MUSIC");

        player.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(serverIp));
        Log.v("", "Set the source is " + serverIp);

        player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);

        player.prepareAsync();
        Log.v("", "After prepareAsync");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.v("IllegalArgumentException", e.toString());
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.v("SecurityException", e.toString());
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.v("IllegalStateException", e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.v("IOException", e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("Exception",e.toString());
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Log.v("onPrepared", "After prepareAsync");
        mp.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("play", e.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("onBufferingUpdate", "Buffering Update");
}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("MediaPlayer onError", "what=" + what + " extra=" + extra);

    return true;
}
```

But it didn’t work. When I click the play button, nothing happens. But if I input some other URL I found on the internet (for example, http://www.example.com/song.mp3), it works.

So can anyone help me? The Log info is below. My mobile is HTC s710e, and my Android version is 4.0.4.

```
11-20 22:28:14.137: V/(580): Init a new MediaPlayer
11-20 22:28:14.137: V/(580): Set the stream type tp STREAM_MUSIC
11-20 22:28:14.147: D/MediaPlayer(580): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
11-20 22:28:14.178: E/Trace(39): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-20 22:28:14.178: V/(580): After prepareAsync
11-20 22:28:14.297: V/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(39): connect on behalf of uid 10044
11-20 22:28:14.339: I/qtaguid(39): Tagging socket 27 with tag 3f500000000(1013) for uid 10044 failed errno=-2
11-20 22:28:14.629: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport(39): Server responded with http status 400
11-20 22:28:14.648: I/qtaguid(39): Untagging socket 27 failed errno=-2
11-20 22:28:14.657: I/AwesomePlayer(39): mConnectingDataSource->connect() returned -1004
11-20 22:28:14.657: E/MediaPlayer(580): error (1, -1004)
11-20 22:28:14.667: E/MediaPlayer(580): Error (1,-1004)
11-20 22:28:14.667: V/MediaPlayer onError(580): what=1 extra=-1004
```

Comment: Maybe it's because the windows media encoder uses a "windows media codec" and Android doesn't support it. I am now meeting a similar problem, where I need to play video streams, and the streams is from Windows Media Encoder. Error -1004 possibly means unsupported codec - I don't know where I can find its meaning...

Comment: OK, just find that MEDIA_ERROR_IO=-1004, which means "File or network related operation errors. "

Answer (score 1):

you can play HLS on android 3.0and 3.0 +  version, older versions doesnt support HLS. This code below, can work on 3.0 + version. To play video all android version you have to use rtsp streaming or http prograssive download.

Player class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;


public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity implements
        OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener,
        OnPreparedListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayerDemo";
    private int mVideoWidth;
    private int mVideoHeight;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceView mPreview;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private String path;
    private Bundle extras;
    private static final String MEDIA = "media";
    private static final int STREAM_VIDEO = 5;
    private boolean mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
    private boolean mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;

    /**
     * 
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        holder = mPreview.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    }

    private void playVideo(Integer Media) {
        doCleanUp();
        try {

            path = "http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/video/famous.3gp";


            // Create a new media player and set the listeners
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
            //mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int percent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate percent:" + percent);

    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion called");
    }

    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onVideoSizeChanged called");
        if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "invalid video width(" + width + ") or height(" + height + ")");
            return;
        }
        mIsVideoSizeKnown = true;
        mVideoWidth = width;
        mVideoHeight = height;
        if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
            startVideoPlayback();
        }
    }

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");
        mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = true;
        if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
            startVideoPlayback();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int i, int j, int k) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged called");

    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed called");
    }


    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated called");
        playVideo(STREAM_VIDEO);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        doCleanUp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        doCleanUp();
    }

    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    private void doCleanUp() {
        mVideoWidth = 0;
        mVideoHeight = 0;
        mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
        mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
    }

    private void startVideoPlayback() {
        Log.v(TAG, "startVideoPlayback");
        holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Main XML

```
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#aaaaaa">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And you have to add to your manifest internet permission

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my version is android 4.0.4. And I just want to play a live audio stream, needn't video. And I can play a `http://www.example.com/somemp3.mp3`, but i cannot play the live stream(the same as radio stream).

Comment: can you give your streaming link to let me test on my custom player ?

Comment: Okay, I just installed the Windows Media Encoder 9 on my PC(Windows XP), and create the http live audio stream to capture the mic, in the windows Media Encoder, the live stream's address is "http://shawn-pc:2340", and the local IP address of shawn-pc is 192.168.1.107, so the streaming link will be http://192.168.1.107:2340. I can play this stream on pc by VLC player or by VLC for android version on my mobile

Comment: I noticed that this message in the debug window: "Server responded with http status 400". So I guess the reason maybe is the http live stream I created is not based on a web server? Then I searched other http live radio stream from BBC, and it works very well. So the problem now is how to create a http live stream base on web server simply? And why VLC for android can play my http live stream but the   MediaPlayer cannot? Whether or not we can found some way to play the live stream?

Comment: Do you have any firewall on your computer ?

Comment: I disabled the firewall, still is the same question